# Give $\mathbb{R}$ the standard (order) topology. Is this theorem going to work in the floor topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Theorem: Give $\mathbb{R}$ the standard (order) topology. Then there is not a collection of
open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that is both pairwise disjoint and uncountable. Is this theorem true in the floor topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

This is how I tried to show it.

Suppose, its not true, then $\exists$ a collection in $\mathbb{R}$ {$A_\alpha$|$\alpha$ $\in$ I} of uncountable open sets, such that $A_\alpha$ $\cap$ $A_\beta$ = $\emptyset$, $\forall$ $\alpha$, $\beta$ $\in$ I, for which I is uncountable. 
Since, $A_\alpha$ is open, then it contains an interval of the form $[a,b)$ (i.e. we have a floor topology of $\mathbb{R}$, and $[a,b)$ where a $<$ b are basic open sets.
Therefore, $\exists$ $r_\alpha$ $\in$ $A_\alpha$, such that $r_\alpha$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Q}$ [since, $\mathbb{Q}$ $\cap$ $[a,b)$ $\neq$ $\emptyset$ $\forall$ $a < b$]. Now, lets look at {$r_\alpha$|$\alpha$ $\in$ I}. 
Since, $A_\alpha$'s are disjoint, therefore $r_\alpha$'s are distincts, $\forall$ $\alpha$ $\in$ I.
Now, {$r_\alpha$|$\alpha$ $\in$ I} $\subset$ $\mathbb{Q}$, therefore this is uncountable since $\mathbb{Q}$ is uncountable. Hence, this is a contradiction. 
Therefore, this theorem is true in the floor topology on $\mathbb{R}$. (Proved).

I think this should work, in case it doesn't pls help me. Also, if it needs a better notation and style please let me know. Appreciate your help and support.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed that same argument works in any space with a countable dense subset (a so-called *separable* space). It works in general spaces.

My more set-theory like proof: suppose $D \subseteq X$ is countable and dense.

If $U_i, i \in I$ is a pairwise disjoint family of non-empty open sets, then all sets $U_i \cap D$ are non-empty, so there is a function (by AC) $$f: I \to D \text{ with } f(i) \in U_i \cap D \text{ for all } i \in I$$

And $f(i) = f(i') \land i \neq i' \implies f(i) \in U_i \cap U_{i'} = \emptyset$, so $f$ is injective so $|I| \le |D|\le \aleph_0$.

Comment: so there is a function (by AC), what's this?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun the Axiom of Choice. It’s an axiom of set theory. See Wikipedia. You were using it in your proof too.

Comment: Aww gotcha, I didnt know u meant dat, sorry!!